# Script to remove whitespace and list items

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a script which would take an input of formatted text (more specifically a copy and pasted list from a word document, likely bullet pointed or numbered) in a text-box input.

After looking into this I have tried using `str_replace` and `preg_replace` but im struggling to get the correct pattern to do what i want here. I'm also unsure on what I can use to 'target' the tabbed space in my pattern. I've tried various ASCII codes with no success (e.g `&#09;`)

**Apologies accidentally hit enter while adding tags**

Examples of pre-script data:

```
1.  Text
2.  Text
3.  Text
4.  Text
```

While it doesn't show clearly here, there is a large tabbed space between the numbering and text when pasting.

Post-script:

```
Text
Text
Text
Text
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?  It will get us into the context of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$output_space = "";
$output_tab = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $lines = explode('<br />', nl2br($_POST['input']));

    foreach($lines as $line){
        $tbl_space = explode(" ", $line);
        $tbl_tab = explode("\t", $line);
        array_shift($tbl_space); // remove first element of the array (everything before the first tab)
        array_shift($tbl_tab);
        $output_space .= trim(implode(" ", $tbl_space))."\r\n";
        $output_tab .= trim(implode("\t", $tbl_tab))."\r\n";
    }

}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="deformat">
Formatted data <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="input" form="deformat" placeholder="pasted formatted text here">
</textarea>
Deformatted data (spaces) <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="output" form="deformat"><?=$output_space?>
</textarea>
Deformatted data (tab)<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="output" form="deformat"><?=$output_tab?>
</textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Clean my data!">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your solution however i'm being given the error:  Undefined variable: lines and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: It's now printing the values but with various errors between each values such as ` implode(): Invalid arguments passed` and `array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`. Here is a link to collabedit: http://collabedit.com/pf7bq

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$arSingleLine = explode(PHP_EOL, $yourPostString);
$arRet = array();
foreach ($arSingleLine as $sSingle)
{
$arRet[] = preg_replace('/^.+\s+/', '', $sSingle);
}

// $arRet holds now every single fixed line...
```

Maybe `PHP_EOL` does not match your client line ending. For splitting every line ending from a single line of code just use `preg_split` and the line endings `\n` `\r` and `\r\n` for UNIX, OS X and Windows line breaks.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i'm being thrown an error of: Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found. I am unfamiliar with the flags for the preg_replace patterns so it might be that I have left something out.

Comment: oh, I am sorry, just add an `/` at the first parameter in `preg_replace` or see my post again, I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're pasting the content in a TextArea and submitting it, you may well lose the correct tabulation in doing so, so instead use the bullets. My PHP is somewhat rusty, so check the code before you use it, but something along the lines of this will work.

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['myFormElement']);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
$bullets = array();
foreach ($lines as $line)
{   
    preg_match("/([^\s]+)\s+(\w*)/", $line,$captured);
    if (count($captured) > 1 ) {
        if (strcmp($captured[1], end($bullets))) {          
            if (count($bullets) > 1 && !strcmp($bullets[count($bullets)-2],$captured[1])) {
                echo '</ul>';
                array_pop($bullets);    
            } else {
                echo '<ul>';
                array_push($bullets, $captured[1]);
            }
        } 
        echo "<li>$captured[2]</li>";
    }
}
while (count($bullets)) {
    echo "</ul>";
    array_pop($bullets);    
}
```